# Regular Expression Find & Replace inserting \1 instead of string

Tags: html, regex, string, replace, dreamweaver

Good day all.

I am using regular expressions in a Find & Replace string in Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.

Here is my Find field:

`( )(4|5|6|7|8|9)(,|</p>)`

Here is my Replace field:

`\1<a href="aup-larondelle-0001.html#p\2">\2</a>\3`

My understanding is that what I've entered SHOULD be instructing the Find & Replace function to find any number 4-9 preceded by a space and followed either by a comma or a close-paragraph tag. It should then replace with string 1, which was the space, followed by `<a href="aup-larondelle-0001.html#p` followed by string 2 which would have been whatever particular number was found, followed by `">` followed by string 2 again (which would be the visible, clickable part of the link), followed by an anchor close-tag, followed by string 3 which would be either a , or a close-paragraph tag.

What I'm actually getting instead is this output:

`\1<a href="aup-larondelle-0001.html#p\2">\2</a>\3`

This is replacing a " 5," in an index I'm building for an e-book. So the find part is working beautifully, but for some reason I'm getting wonky results with the replace.

Any thoughts on what's screwing me up? Thank you enormously for your time!

Edit: Added code-markers so my code would display. Sorry about that!

Edit 2: Just to be clear, what I'm saying is that I am literally getting `\1` instead of the actual value of string 1 from the find function.

Edit 3: Just to indicate that I have done some research, I am drawing the basic format for my find & replace from Liz Castro's fantastically useful blog, "Pigs, Gourds, and Wikis". Her entry for July 20, 2010 recommends this format and can be found at [this link](http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/2010/07/creating-index-for-epub-with-indesign.html). I have requested assistance there as well, but whereas Ms. Castro is one woman, Stack Overflow is legion. :)

ANSWER: I have found an answer to my question. It turns out that in Adobe Dreamweaver, they don't use \ to indicate a string. They use $ instead. Thus, substituting $ for every occurrence of \ resulted in a useable output. Huzzah! (can't answer my own question for 8 hours apparently due to being a newbie)

Comment: Try to change `\1` to `$1` in your replacement string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the backreference problem, your regex can use some improvements. Tested in Dreamweaver 6:

Search: `([4-9])(,|</p>)`

Replace: `<a href="aup-larondelle-0001.html#p$1">$1</a>$2`

1. As you noted, backreferences in Dreamweaver should be of the form `$1` rather than `\1`
2. There is no need to capture the space. You can directly replace by a space.
3. The expression `4|5|6|7|8|9` can be expressed much more compactly by the character range `[4-9]` (character ranges are one of the workhorses of regex).

Comment: Thanks. I was blissfully unaware! :)